# Win 10 UWP Mapcontrol PointerMoved event missing

Tags: vb.net, uwp

Until some month ago this code was able to rise the PointerMoved event:

```html
<maps:MapControl Name="myMap" Canvas.ZIndex="1">  </maps:MapControl>


<StackPanel x:Name="overlay" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Canvas.ZIndex="5" Background="Transparent" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
```

It seems that something changed since this post has been published.

Right now I can't get anymore the MyMap_PointerMoved or MyMap_PointerPressed with or without the empty stackpanel over the map.

Curiously MyMap_PointerMoved event fires only if I leave the zoom + and - signs visible.

Event fires only when mouse is over the those sings.

I've added a polygon mapelement on the map. Only the MyMap_MapElementPointerEnter/Exited events fires.

Any idea how to solve this issues and make the maps work again?

Tnx. Stefano

Comment: It seems we can not use `PointerMoved` in  `MapControl`. You should be able to find another event to instead of it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. For some reason I can't evaluate the .png image I have used until now in causing the crash. Replaced with a new one solved the problem.